Встраивание YouTube видео без маркеров
Есть задача на установление видео с YouTube в качестве фонового изображения. Секция с видео.


<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGwWNGJdvx8?showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;fs=0&amp;mute=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;controls=0&amp;disablekb=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
  referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>



Возникшая проблема с автовоспроизведениям решилась тут. Теперь вопрос как убрать маркеры которые лепяться плеером ?

Почитал документацию по API. Вроде как за это должен отвечать атрибут showinfo=0 но почему-то не срабатывает, и при старте видео как и при hover оно продолжает отображать маркеры. Как это можно исправить ?

Хорошо в России работает Youtube без монетизации. А вот если к вам зайдет посетитель из другой страны, то он еще и кучу реклам вставит помимо баннера

Те кто размещают видео с ютуба убирают рекламу со своих роликов, не интерисовался как именно они это делают, но их видео не монитезируються, а акаунты платные. Вот пример. https://pacificvisionfoundation.org/   Но я не могу понять, как добились что этих маркеров там нету.

Параметр showinfo устарел с сентября 2018 года и больше не поддерживается YouTube, важно помнить о соблюдении условий использования платформы. Согласно правилам YouTube, скрытие логотипа и информационной панели без согласования может являться нарушением условий использования. Это может привести к ограничениям доступа к API YouTube или другим юридическим последствиям. Рекомендуется изучить возможности альтернативного подхода, который позволит интегрировать видео с соблюдением правил YouTube.
с помощью стилей можно добиться, желаемых эффектов...
⛔❗❗❗ Такой подход нарушает условия использования YouTube ❗❗❗⛔



.iframe-wrapper {
  height: 280px; /* Высота контейнера */
  overflow: hidden; /* Скрытие части iframe, выходящей за пределы контейнера */
}

.iframe-wrapper iframe {
  height: 400px; /* Высота iframe */
  margin-top: -60px; /* Смещение iframe вверх для скрытия части верхней части видеоплеера */
}
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe width="500" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7dYKr4zHi78?autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>



вот ссылки, которые могут быть полезны, там есть попытки программистов создать идентичный сценарий, но решения, там я не нашла, как и сказала, showinfo устарел игнорируется с 25 сентября 2018 г

Hide YouTube video controls
Youtube Javascript API
Can you hide the controls
How to remove youtube branding
Hiding YouTube embed

пример, который вы указали в комментариях, видимо использует локальную загрузку/ css/ (это лишь предположения), и соответсвенно поэтому у них нет маркеров.
я бы лично, нашла способ локальной загрузки, если я хочу дать задний фон без лого ютуба. Скачать локально - это выход, который я вижу

Неее, это не подходит. Все више вами написаное можно заменить стилем. iframe{pointer-events: none;} Эффект тот же: Не можешь навестись на элемент - не будет hover Хотелось бы как-то без костылей.
